# Show that the following is a bounded linear operator on $L^2(R_+)$ Calculate the adjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators, strong-convergence

The following is a question I have been working on for some time with help from my teacher. Unfortunately we have a solution but are not 100% confident with it. Some guidance on if part(s) of our solution are incorrect would be greatly appreciated. Any help is most welcome. Thankyou!

Show that B is a bounded linear operator on $L^{2}_{(R_+)}$. Calculate the adjoint operator.

Set $R_+=\{x \in R:x \ge 0\}$ For $f \in L^{2}(R_+)$.
Define: $$Bf(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t) \ dt, x>0.$$

Showing boundedness. Assume $Bf(x)$ is linear (Shown later).

We wish to show that this is continuous in $0$. 
By definition, we have that $x$ is dense in $L^{2}_{(R_+)}$. 
We also know that $f_n$ is uniformly bounded (Unsure on this part?)

Let $f_{n} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(R_+)$

Define $F_{n}(x):=\dfrac{1}{x^{2}} \lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_{n}(t) \ dt\rvert^{2}$ with $F_{n}(x) \in L^2(R_+)$

Then we know $F_{n}(0)\equiv 0 \ \ \ \forall n \ \  As \ f_{n} \to 0$

Claim: $\lvert\lvert(F_{n}(x))\rvert\rvert_{L^2_{(R_+)}}\to 0$

\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert(F_{n}(x))\rvert\rvert_{L^2_{(R_+)}}&=[\int_{0}^{\infty}\lvert\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \ dt\rvert^{2}\rvert^{2} dx]^{1/2} \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} dx 
\end{align}

For 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}} \ dx \to 0 \ As \ F_{n}(0) \equiv 0
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
\lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} \le \int_{0}^{x}\lvert f_n(t)\rvert^{2} \ dt \to 0 \ As \ \ \ f_{n}(t) \to 0 \ \  (Holder's \ Inequality)
\end{align}

For $\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} \ dx$ we have that:

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}} \ dx \le M
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
\lvert\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} \le \int_{0}^{x}\lvert f_n(t)\rvert^{2} \ dt \to 0 \ As \ \ \ f_{n}(t) \to 0 \ \  (Holder's \ Inequality)
\end{align}

So $f_{n} \in L^{2}_{(R_+)}$

Hence, by density, $f_{n} \to f$ as $n \to \infty$, and we have that:
\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert(Bf(x))\rvert\rvert_{L^2_{(R_+)}}&=(\int_{0}^{\infty}\lvert\dfrac{1}{x} \ \int_{0}^{x}f(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} \ dx)^{1/2} \\
&=(\int_{0}^{1}\lvert\dfrac{1}{x} \ \int_{0}^{x}f(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} \ dx)^{1/2} +(\int_{1}^{\infty}\lvert\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t) \ dt\rvert^{2} \ dx)^{1/2} \\
&\le \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x} \ dx \ \int_{0}^{x}\lvert f(t)\rvert \ dt+\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \ dx \ \int_{0}^{x}\lvert f(t)\rvert \ dt \\
&\le M\lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_{L^2_{(R_+)}}
\end{align}

Therefore $Bf(x)$ is bounded for some constant $M > 0$.

Linearity: Let $\alpha,\beta \in R_+$.
Then 
$$ \begin{align*} 
B(\alpha f+\beta f)(x) &=(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x})\int_{0}^{x}(\alpha f(t)+ \beta f(t))dt \\ &=(\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\alpha f(t)dt +\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\beta f(t)dt) \\ &=\alpha Bf(x)+\beta Bf(x)   \end{align*} $$

Therefore $B(f(x))$ is linear.

Adjoint operator:

We need to find $B^{*}$. We know by definition $(Bf,u)_{L^{2}_(R_+)}=(f,B^{*}u)_{L^{2}_(R_+)}$.

Consider the characteristic 
\begin{align} 
\chi(t,x) &=\{1 \ \ x > t \\ &= \{0  \ \ x \le t 
&
\end{align}

From above we have:

\begin{align}
(B(f),u)_{L^{2}_{(R_+)}} &=\int_{0}^{\infty}[\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} \ f(t) \ dt] \ \chi(t,x)  \ u(x) dx \\ &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} \ f(t) \ \chi(t,x) \ dt \ u(x) dx \\ 
&=\int_{0}^{x} \ f(t) \ dt \ \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \ u(x) \ \chi(t,x) \ dx  \\
&=\int_{0}^{x} \ f(t) \ dt \ \int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \ u(x) \ dx  \\
&=(f,B^{*}u)
\end{align}

Hence $B^{*}=\int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \ dx$

The part I am most unsure on is my solution to $B(f(x))$ at the start. I am unsure I have applied the $L^{2}_{(R_+)}$ norm correctly.

Comment: I think for the purpose of this (to my memory, this question has been worked on quite a while), f is pointwise integrable. Unfortunately Bf must be defined as this was a Master's level question I was asked to complete for a class. 

Otherwise I am unsure what you mean? Inside an $L^{p}$ space does local integrability apply to a function? 

I would have considered $f_{n}(t) \to f(t)$ was sufficient given compact support.

Comment: We have that also $f_{n}(t)$ is a converging subsequence of $f(t)$ which then has compact support. So using strong convergence for $f_{n}(t) \to 0$ seemed sufficient for $f(t) \to 0$. This would make local integrability not needed to my understanding?

Comment: What is $f_n$ here?

Comment: $f_{n}$ is a sequence of functions that begin in $R_{+}$ and have compact support.I was unsure if we needed uniform boundedness to state that $f_{n} \to 0$.

Comment: Do you mean to choose $f_n$ so they converge to $f$ in $L^2$?

Comment: Yes because if a sequence $f_{n} \to 0$  (strongly), and $f_{n} \to f$, then $f \to 0$ strongly. 

I should clarify that since $f \in L^2_{{R_+}}$, then by definition we use $f_n \in {{R_+}}$ as $f_n \to f$.

Comment: To clarify. We have a linear mapping for $Bf(x)$ that goes from $L^2_{(R_+)} \to L^2_{(R_+)}$. We have $Bf_{n} \to Bf(0)$ when $f_{n} \to 0$ (True for all linear mappings). If we can then show that $f_{n} \to f$ we are done from there. This is true due to density (I believe.)

Unfortunately at times my teacher ran away with the problem and did not explain certain jumps in much detail, so I am doing my best to fill them in, as he is now away. This is what I have managed to come up with mostly after he helped with defining $F_{n}(x)$.

Comment: Hi, I have made some changes realising I made a fair few errors calculating my norms for the first part. The way I understand my $f_{n}$ was that it was a compact supported sequence of functions in $R_+$. I am trying to show that for $f \in L^{2}_{(R_+)}$ we can simply use $f_{n}$ as a sequence in $F_{n}(x)$ to find each from using the norm. I then related that back to $f$ by the fact $f_{n} \to f \in L^{2}_{(R_+)}$ due to density if $f_{n} \in L^{2}_{(R_+)}$.

Comment: What's the purpose of considering $\{f_n\}$? Why can't you just write down $\|Bf\|_{L^2}=(\int_0^\infty\cdots$?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue with your boundedness proof. Your argument boils down to the following calculation:
\begin{align*}
\|Bf\|_{L^2}&=(\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt\right|^2dx)^{1/2}\\
&\leq(\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{x}\int_0^\infty|f(t)|\mathbf1_{[0,x]}dt\right)^2dx)^{1/2}\\
&\leq(\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\|f\|_{L^2}^2xdx)^{1/2}\\
&=(\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x})^{1/2}\|f\|_{L^2}.
\end{align*}
As you can see, this does not prove boundedness because $1/x$ is not integrable at zero or infinity. The inequality that is not tight is Cauchy-Schwarz, since $|f(t)|$ can never be an exact multiple of $\mathbf1_{[0,x]}(t)$. Therefore a stronger argument is needed to prove boundedness.

Comment: Hi Stan.
Thankyou very much for your input so far.

My teacher had a similar thought regarding Cauchy-Schwarz not being tight enough and defining $F_{n}(x)$ and $f_{n}$ was an attempt to help with this. I am inclined to agree that perhaps $f_{n}$ and even $F_{n}(x)$ are probably not necessary as this was an exam question not worth very much, so it should not need a high level of detail (I would hope, considering the other parts of this question were easier and worth more.)

The hint(s) the person who wrote the question gave was to use compact support, density & continuity arguments.

Comment: On a note for the adjoint operator, should I have $(B(f),u)=(f,B^{*}u)$, so my $B^{*}$ at the end should instead be $\int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \ dx$